# Need to Create a SQL View from List of Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

Trying to create a view where all the tables have the same fields but different data in them.  We have a table that we track each of these tables, and track which ones are active.  So I want a view that will tie all the active tables together in one view.

Say you have tables A, B, and C.  Only B and C are active, table 1 lists each table and which is active.  So form table 1 we can get the table names we need for the view.

It escapes me on how to do this on the SQL Server (2008 version)

Comment: This is really bad design. Could you give an example of what you really try to do and we might be able to help you find a better DB design in which you don't need dynamic queries

Answer (score 0):

This does sound like a bad design.  It is better to store all the data in one table and use partitioning methods to access it.

Here, though, is one method to do what you want:

```
create view abc as
    select a.*
    from a cross join
         (select 1 from table1 where status = 'active' and tablename = 'a')
    union all
    select b.*
    from b cross join
         (select 1 from table1 where status = 'active' and tablename = 'b')
    select c.*
    from c cross join
         (select 1 from table1 where status = 'active' and tablename = 'c');
```

I don't really recommend this approach.  It is intended simply to show that it is possible.  I chose `cross join`, because the subquery is evaluated only once and this might be an optimization for the underlying execution code.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use a table partition: [What is a table partition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1821404/what-is-table-partitioning)

Here is an example:[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188730.aspx)